# Object-oriented design question, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sorry I'm still a noob and just learning to program as I go and want to start out on the right foot by learning good design up front.  I am using the CLLocationManager and MKReverseGecoder to get my location.  In my MKReverseGecoderDelegate method, I create my annotation to show on the MKMapView.  In my callout, I use a detail disclosure indicator to bring up another UITableView that displays your current address nicely as opposed to looking at the little black callout bubble.

What is a good way for my DetailViewController (the UITableView) to get the data?  Do I have my first class have ivars for address, state, zipcode.  In my MKReverseGecoderDelegate, set those ivars when I get that information.  (The reason I would think I would need ivars is because my method to get that information in the MKReverseGeocoderDelegate is separate from the displayDetailViewController).   And then do I have my DetailViewController have those same values, and when I go to display the DetailViewController, set those same variables?  It seems redundant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option

Declare custom class inheriting NSObject like

```
@interface YourClassName : NSObject 
{
     NSString *address;
     NSString *state;
     NSString *zipcode;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *address;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *state;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *zipcode;
@end

@implementation YourClassName
@synthesize address,state,zipcode;

-(void)dealloc
{
     [super dealloc];
     [address release];
     [state release];
     [zipcode release];
}
@end


//Create object of YourClassName and set values
YourClassName *objYourClassName = [[YourClassName alloc] init];
objYourClassName.address = @"YourValue";
objYourClassName.state = @"YourValue";
objYourClassName.zipcode = @"YourValue";

Pass this object to your DetailViewController by one method after creating method like

-(void)setDetailsForDetailViewController:(YourClassName*)pObjYourClassName
{
     //self.objOfYourClassName is property declared in your detailviewcontroller.
     self.objOfYourClassName = pObjYourClassName; //You can use self.objOfYourClassName to set values in TableViewController. 
}
```

If you stuck any where let me know I would be glad to help you fix that.

Comment: Yeah it pretty much makes sense. My follow up would be, so would I create that new object in my MKReverseGeocoderDelegate method since that's where I get the address information.  Then how do I pass that object to my new set method as I only want to pass it in a separate method where the detail disclosure button of the callout is pressed.

Comment: Do I have my class where I use the MKReverseGeocoderDelegate have an ivar of YourClassName, set it, and then pass it in later in my other method?  Is this the "Has-a" relationship?  Composition?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the reverse geocoding on demand, initialize the DetailViewController with the coordinate of the annotation. Something like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocation*)location {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"DetailController" bundle:nil]) {
        self.location = location;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is a common pattern to create the controllers, because it makes it clear for the controller's user that the controller depends on a location parameter. The other alternatives (global variables, or a singleton) are not so clean because they hide information and make the controller harder to understand and unit test.

Then let the controller launch an asynchronous task to do the geocoding, set itself as delegate, and present the information when it's done.